# Newbie question about exodus wallet!

Tags: wallet

I just installed exodus,
1) why the program didn't even ask, do you want a new address? it's generated automatically!
2) when I click recieve on my bitcoin wallet, there are two different addresses generated(that I can click next or backward to chose them), interestingly enough they are not there to be chosen when I click send. which address is mine?

Thanks

Comment: All of the addresses are yours.

Comment: No, I am talking about just the bitcoin tab,

Comment: I have two addresses in bitcoin tab, install and see yourself,
and If I have two bitcoin addresses why is that?

Comment: When you want people to pay you, you can give them different addresses, which means you can keep track of who paid and who didn't.

Comment: so it means I have two different private Keys??

Answer (score 3):

Here is the explanation: https://support.exodus.io/article/81-how-do-i-generate-a-new-bitcoin-address

> Your bitcoin addresses are reusable, however, some users may want to
>   generate new bitcoin addresses for privacy purposes. If you would like
>   to generate a new address, click on the arrow to the right of the QR
>   code in your bitcoin receive window.
>
> You start out with two bitcoin addresses. As each address is used, a
>   new one will generate. This way, you always have an unused address
>   available to you.